# Added a new route in app-routing.module.ts - ngxAdmin is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, ngx-admin

I am customizing the ngx-admin template, I was trying to add new module in app module. And added its route in app-routing.module.ts. But its not working when i tried it open. It got stuck at loading. 
There is no error in console too. So I'm not understanding what might be the problem.

I have added this SignModule outside pages, not inside pages

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { ExtraOptions, RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import {
  NbAuthComponent,
  NbLoginComponent,
  NbRegisterComponent,
  NbLogoutComponent,
  NbRequestPasswordComponent,
  NbResetPasswordComponent,
} from "@nebular/auth";

const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: "pages",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("../app/pages/pages.module").then(m => m.PagesModule),
  },
   //Newly added Module
  {
    path: "sign",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("../app/sign/sign.module").then(m => m.SignModule),
  },
  {
    path: "auth",
    component: NbAuthComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: NbLoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: "login",
        component: NbLoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: "register",
        component: NbRegisterComponent
      },
      {
        path: "logout",
        component: NbLogoutComponent
      },
      {
        path: "request-password",
        component: NbRequestPasswordComponent,
      },
      {
        path: "reset-password",
        component: NbResetPasswordComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: "", redirectTo: "sign", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "**", redirectTo: "pages" },
];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: false,
  enableTracing: true,
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

This is the new module I added. SignModule

sign.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { ThemeModule } from '../@theme/theme.module';

import { SignComponent } from './sign.component';
import { SigninModule } from './signin/signin.module';
import { SignupModule } from './signup/signup.module';
import { SignRoutingModule } from './sign-routing.module';


@NgModule({

  imports: [
    SignRoutingModule,
    ThemeModule,
    SigninModule,
    SignupModule,
  ],
  declarations: [SignComponent],
})
export class SignModule { }
```

sign-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SigninComponent } from './signin/signin.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { SignComponent } from './sign.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SignComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'signin',
        component: SigninComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'signup',
        component: SignupComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'signin',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      }
    ]
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SignRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the nebular theme used by ngx-admin. Only those pages/components are displayed which are wrapped in `nb-layout`

The spinner for pages which are wrapped under `nb-layout`. Hence it skips displaying the pages/components you added. 
And the correct way of doing it is

```
<nb-layout>
    <nb-layout-column>
      // Your content
    </nb-layout-column>
  </nb-layout>
```